# moment.js silently fails when being loaded as an AMD module. All other modules are OK

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am attempting to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/) in a project. I load many, many other AMD modules, but [loading moment.js as an AMD module per the docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/require-js/) is undefined.

```
define([
    'vnd/moment',
    'vnd/ractive',
    'vnd/agave',
    'vnd/superagent',
], function(moment, Ractive, agave, superagent) {
    console.log('moment', moment)         // moment is undefined
    console.log('Ractive', Ractive)       // works
    console.log('agave', agave)           // works
    console.log('superagent', superagent) // works
})
```

**Every other module other than moment.js returns something**. Only moment is undefined.

There are no errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured this out. Unlike most AMD modules, Moment doesn't actually return anything when loaded as a module, instead it creates the global `window.moment`.

```
define([
    'vnd/moment'
], function(unused) {
    log('moment', window.moment)
})
```

I've [filed an issue to fix this](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1676)  on GitHub.